# How to assign partial parameters from a dataframe on purrr pmap function

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have the following data frame

```r
library(tidyverse)

param_df <- data.frame(
  y_high = 10:12,
  x = 1:3 + 0.1,
  y = 3:1 - 0.1,
  z = letters[1:3]
) %>% 
  as.tibble() %>% 
  mutate(z =  as.character(z))

param_df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   y_high     x     y z    
#>    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     10  1.10 2.90  a    
#> 2     11  2.10 1.90  b    
#> 3     12  3.10 0.900 c
```

And the following function

```r
  myfunc <- function(x=NULL, y=NULL, z=NULL) {
  # The function is simpy printing the sum
  cat(" The sum of ", z ," is ", x + y , "\n")
}
```

What the function does is to take only `x` and `y` columns from `param_df` and simply print the sum.

I tried this

```r
param_df %>%
  purrr::pmap(myfunc, x = x, y = y, z=z)

# # Later would like to have the flexibility to do 
# param_df %>%
#  purrr::pmap(myfunc, x = x, y = y_high, z=z)
```

But it gives the following error message:

```r
Error in .f(x = .l[[c(1L, i)]], y = .l[[c(2L, i)]], z = .l[[c(3L, i)]],  : 
  formal argument "x" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

What's the right way to do it?

The desired final output with `purrr::pmap` is

```r
The sum a is 4
The sum b is 4
The sum c is 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function only has side effects, so you want `walk` rather than `map`.

`walk2` will take 2 arguments and apply a function.

```
purrr::walk2(param_df$x, param_df$y, myfunc)
# The sum is  4 
# The sum is  4 
# The sum is  4
```

Edit:
For your example.

```
myfunc <- function(x=NULL, y=NULL, z=NULL) {
  # The function is simpy printing the sum
  cat(" The sum of ", z ," is ", x + y , "\n")
}

param_df %>%
  with(
    pwalk(list(x, y, z), .f = myfunc))
 # The sum of  a  is  4 
 # The sum of  b  is  4 
 # The sum of  c  is  4
```

Or, with `magrittr` special pipes.

```
library('magrittr')

param_df %$%
  pwalk(list(x, y, z), .f = myfunc)
#  The sum of  a  is  4 
#  The sum of  b  is  4 
#  The sum of  c  is  4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. In actuality, the param is more than 2. I updated my example. How can I modify your code?

Comment: pmap/pwalk can be used like this: pwalk(list(param_df$x, param_df$y), .f = myfunc)